# Scroll function activates before scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

So i have this code on my page

jQuery

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 785) {
          $('#navbar').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
          $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed');
      }
  });
```

css

```
.fixed {position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}
```

**My problem**
When i load the page #navbar seems to have .addClass('fixed'); before scrolling. If i scroll just 1px after loading the page then .removeClass('fixed') activates and is activated until i dont get below 785px.

How do i fix so fixed doesnt activate when i load the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove it on load?

```
$(function() {  $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed');  }); // this should remove it on load
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 785) {
        $('#navbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try 'resetting' the state once DOM loads, as follows:

```
function _setClass() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 785) {
        $('#navbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
}

_setClass();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    _setClass();
});

$(function(){ _setClass() });
```

hope that helped.